Why the external monitor does not show Ubuntu VM?
I have a Ubuntu Linux laptop, I used virt-manager to install a Ubuntu VM. The VM worked great. Now I connect the laptop to a monitor using HDMI cable, but on monitor I can only see the host Ubuntu, I cannot see VM. At laptop screen, I put the whole screen for VM, but still all I can see is host linux.
How to make VM show up on the external monitor?
The host Ubuntu is 18.04 and the VM ubuntu is 20.04.

Do you have virt-viewer installed?  Reference https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/virtual-machine-manager
